# Double pipe (||) in AngularJS Expressions

Tags: angularjs

On my controller I have something like:

`this.user = {
 first_name: "David", 
 full_name: "David Silva"
}`

The data I get sometimes doesn't have full_name, so I tried this expression:

`{{user.full_name || user.first_name}}`

It seems to be working but after closer inspection I realize that it doesn't behave how it would in regular JS. I was expecting that if full_name was undefined or empty it would try the other one, but instead if the expression after the `||` is valid it will  evaluate to that regardless of the expression on the left.

I couldn't find out why, and I would like to know more about the way this is interpreted to take proper advantage of it.

Comment: Please provide the code from your controller as well as the template. Are you using `this` on the controller? If so, then the controller is being used as a viewmodel so you would access the data somewhat differently than if you were using scope.

Comment: I can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oa9JsDwW1TVjwxIYzov9?p=preview. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue either: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/12487/) - can you extend this fiddle/create a new one that reproduces the issue?

Comment: There's no really a problem, kinda, I'm just confused on how it works, I will add a plunkr, one minute.

Comment: Random I wasn't able to reproduce either. http://plnkr.co/edit/FvwEmAcnqGyX6iLsJUcQ?p=preview I will try and look for other things that could be getting on the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had trouble with the `||` in angularJS.  In order to get the same effect, I've found it best to use the ternary operator.  So you write it like this:

```
user.full_name ?  user.full_name : user.first_name
```

This is equivalent to

```
if(user.full_name)
    return user.full_name
else
    return user.first_name
```

The ternary operator is a little more verbose, but I have found that it works, whereas `||` has issues.